# Export an excel from my datatable with a Savefile dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am using VB.Net. I want to export an excel from my datatable with a Savefile dialog. But I get error as:

> "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode
>   before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has
>   STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a
>   debugger is attached to the process."

I have googled alot, but for my "Web application" it could not be resolved.

here is my code:

```
 Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _
   Then
        ExportExcel(dt, "Appraisals" + value.ToString())
    End If
```

Comment: Have you considered posting the actual code that makes the OLE calls?

Comment: Nothing is wrong there in OLE calling code. This error occurs on opening of SavefileDialog line, here :   
If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _
       Then

Comment: Waitaminute, are you trying to use a Windows.Forms SaveFileDialog (code reference) in an Asp.net/webforms (post tags) app?

Comment: @sdf Actually i have tried many savefile dialog(other than this Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK), But all of those returned me the same error.
I am still stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

I Can't Find the error of your code but you can try mine =D

```
Dim workBookName As String = "Computers"

If Not workBookName = "" Then
   SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel WorkBook|*.xlsx"
   SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
   Location = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
   ExportExcel(dt, "Appraisals" + value.ToString())
Else
   MsgBox("Please enter Worksheet Name", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Export To Excel")
End If
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong there in OLE calling code. This error occurs on opening of SavefileDialog line, here :   
If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _ Then